# Compositions and products on Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Does anybody have a good textbook reference for someone who wants to begin studying products and compositions in Sobolev spaces, where the underlying domain is either $\mathbb{R}^n$ or an open subset of it.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear what "products and compositions in Sobolev spaces" covers.  A fairly recent text, *Sobolev Spaces: with Applications to Elliptic Partial Differential Equations* by Vladimir Maz'ya and Tatyana O. Shaposhnikova, is available as a Google eBook.  The first chapter is free to read on the Web, so it should be possible to gain a good idea whether it meets your expectations.